# Javascript regex ends with pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regex in javascript to identify string representations of arbitrary javascript functions found in json, ie. something like

```
{
  "key": "function() { return 'I am a function'; }"
}
```

It's easy enough to identify the start, but I can't figure out how to identify the ending double quotes since the function might also contain escaped double quotes. My best try so far is

```
/"\s*function\(.*\)[^"]*/g
```

which works nicely if there are no double quotes in the function string. The end of a json key value will end with a double quote and a subsequent comma or closing bracket. Is there some way to retrieve all characters (including newline?) until a negated pattern such as

```
not "/s*, and not "/s*}
```

... or do I need to take a completely different approach without regex?

Here's is the current test data I'm working with:
http://regexr.com/39pvi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
"\s*function\(.*\)(?:\\.|[^\\"])*
```

It matches also the inbetween `\"` escaped double quotes.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/oY5jU1/4)

Comment: it's not working if there is `\n` in the body of the function like this: `"function() { 
  return 'hello \n fun
  ction stuff'; }"`

Comment: it works, see http://regex101.com/r/oY5jU1/1 . `[^"\\]*` would match newline characters also.

Comment: if there is any `\n` present in this `()` block then he need to change the regex like `"\s*function\([\S\s]*?\)(?:[^"\\]|\\")*`

Comment: You can switch the two parts and leave out the \\: `"\s*function\(.*\)(?:\\"|[^"])*"`. See http://regex101.com/r/oY5jU1/3